# soapheader authentication

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, soap

I cannot get my client to reconise AuthHeaderValue which visual studio adds to proxy class
I have seen many examples but could find nothing on how to resolve this.

Soap class

```
     public class AuthHeader : SoapHeader
     {
        public string Username;
        public string Password;

     }
```

web service

```
     public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
     {
        public AuthHeader Authentication; ** where does visual studio append value to proxy 

    [SoapHeader("Authentication", Required = true)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string security()
    {
        if (Authentication.Username == "test" &&
            Authentication.Password == "test")
        {
            return "authenticated";
        }
        else
        {
            return "get lost";
        }            
    }
```

client

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceReference1.AuthHeader auth = new ServiceReference1.AuthHeader();
        auth.Username = "test";
        auth.Password = "test";

        ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient ser = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
        ser.AuthHeaderValue = auth;  ** does not reconise authheadervalue
        String message = ser.security();
        Console.WriteLine(message);

    }
```

Comment: Fixed it. added service reference instead of web reference. duu

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the authentication parameter value as `TRUE` for the header.
Check the full solution [here](http://tamedotnet.blogspot.com/2013/04/soap-header-authentication-for-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebService service = new WebService();
       service.Authentication.Username = "a";
       service.Authentication.Password = "a";
       string str = service .CheckAuthn();
```

Apply that code

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public ServiceAuthHeader Credentials;
public class ServiceAuthHeader : SoapHeader
{
    public string Username;
    public string Password;
}
```

to security method change like below

```
 public static string Validate(ServiceAuthHeader soapHeader)
 {
        string error_msg = "Pass";
        if (soapHeader == null)
        {
            error_msg = "No soap header was specified.";
        }
        else if (soapHeader.Username == null || soapHeader.Username == "")
        {
           error_msg = "Username was not supplied for authentication in SoapHeader.";
        }
        else if (soapHeader.Password == null || soapHeader.Password == "")
        {
           error_msg = "Password was not supplied for authentication in SoapHeader.";
        }

        else if (soapHeader.Username != "test" || soapHeader.Password != "test")
        {
             error_msg = "Please pass the proper username and password for this service.";
        }

      return error_msg;
 }
```

keep a method with your credential in some common class or some where else

```
 public static void AuthValidatoin(WebserviceObject callwebservice)
 {
       ServiceAuthHeader serviceAuthHeaderValue = new LocalERPWebService.ServiceAuthHeader();
       serviceAuthHeaderValue.Username = "test";
       serviceAuthHeaderValue.Password = "test";
       callwebservice.ServiceAuthHeaderValue = serviceAuthHeaderValue;
 }
```

when your calling the web service use the above method to authenticate the service like below

```
 WebserviceObject CallWebService = new WebserviceObject();
 common.AuthValidatoin(CallWebService);
```