# SOAP Header Authentication in WP7/8 App

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, soap, windows-phone-8

I am having a webservice like given below:

```
                      POST /mobileservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: services.segwaycommunications.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://services.segwaycommunications.com/ValidateUser"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <PlatformAuthentication xmlns="http://services.segwaycommunications.com">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </PlatformAuthentication>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ValidateUser xmlns="http://services.segwaycommunications.com">
      <username xmlns="">string</username>
      <password xmlns="">string</password>
      <resellerid xmlns="">int</resellerid>
    </ValidateUser>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now, as we can see here soap header need authentication via a class platformauthentication.

Can anyone help how could I make authentication in windows phone 7/8 app using this webservice?

Ihave searched a lot but nothing has given me a proper solution.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

as per my opinion Json parsing is best

so firrst you need to download Newtonsoft.Json dll for parse web serevice

Just follow bellow step

**Step1:** Add Service References by right click on add References.

**Step2:** Now put your web service link on Service References and press go button, And also add Namespace of service Reference 
[image]

**Step3:** Now add using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` name space in your .cs file

**Step4:** Now add bellow code in your cs file

```
 WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient ws = new WhatsupServices.WhatsUpServiceSoapClient();
ws.ContactUsJSONCompleted += ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted;
ws.ContactUsJSONAsync(txtContactUsName.Text, txtContactUsPhone.Text, txtContactUsEmail.Text, txtContactUsComment.Text);
```

**step6:** now genrate your resopnce method

```
 void ws_ContactUsJSONCompleted(object sender, dynamic e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(LogIn.NetworkBusyMsg, LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            }
            else
            {
                busyIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                string Result = e.Result;
                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(Result);
                string ResultCode = (string)obj["ResultCode"];
                string ResponceMessage = (string)obj["ResponseMessage"];

                if (ResultCode == "1")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Thank you for your message. We'll get back to you soon.", LogIn.MsgHdr, MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    NavigationService.GoBack();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Hope it will help you.

If any query than comment here.I wll help you

**Soap header authentication**

[soap header authentication solve in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158545/soapheader-authentication)

[Custom authentication for web service using soap header](http://stalal.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/custom-authentication-for-webservice-using-soapheader/)

[Using SOAP Headers to Validate Clients](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rog_21/soapheaders05172007120046PM/soapheaders.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but problem part is

 <soap:Header>
    <PlatformAuthentication xmlns="http://services.segwaycommunications.com">
      <UserName>string</UserName>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </PlatformAuthentication>
  </soap:Header>

I have to first authenticate the platform then and only then i can use whatever service is provided.... Help if you know coding about how to do soap header authentication.